# AfterReturning advice not executed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

```java
@Component
Class A {
 
    public String methodA() {
      return methodB();
    }
        
        
    @Publish
    public String methodB() {
      return "abc";
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class PublishEvents {
    
    @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(Publish)", returning = "retVal")
    public void sendEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
        system.out.println("sending event");
    }
}
```

So I have an aspect class `PublishEvents` defined with `AfterReturning` Advice. This advice gets executed when I use `@Publish` which is a custom defined annotation, over `methodA` of class A but it does not get executed when I put it over `methodB` of class A. Note that `methodB` is called from `methodA`.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: I don't know how this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP is proxy-based, which means that an additional class for proxying bean calls is created by Spring, for more details about proxy mechanisms check [the link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-proxying).

The key thing to understand is that calls on that component reference are calls on the proxy. To make it more clear, other beans, that autowire the `A` component, actually contain the proxied instance, not the component instance itself. As a result, the proxy can delegate to all the interceptors (advice) relevant to that particular method call.

However, any method calls it may make on itself, such as `methodA` invoking `methodB` in your case, will be invoked against the instance itself, not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation will not result in the `AfterReturning` advice getting a chance to run.

Unlike Spring AOP, AspectJ has no issues with self-invocation since it's not a proxy-based AOP framework. Check [Indra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48717429/10231374) for more details and examples.

For reference: [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)